# Python Logging to head of logfile?

Tags: python, logging, reverse

I use python logging and would like the latest log entry to be at the head of the log file, rather than the tail.

I cannot find anything in https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html that appears useful for appending a logger record at the head of the logfile instead of the tail.

This is my logger:  ("Carl" is my GoPiGo3 robot)

```
import logging

# create logger
logger = logging.getLogger('lifelog')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
loghandler = logging.FileHandler('/home/pi/Carl/life.log')
logformatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s|%(message)s',"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
loghandler.setFormatter(logformatter)
logger.addHandler(loghandler)
#logger.info('-------------')
```

and I log with:

```
     logger.info('<something to log>')
```

Is there a python logging module intrinsic solution?
Do I have to write my own handler?

Comment: Inserting something at the beginning of a file displaces everything that comes after it, so the bigger the file, the more an insert will cost. That would go counter to the efforts of the `logging` module to be sparing in its use of resources.

Comment: Would it make more sense to reverse the file at the end of the program?  Or just change what viewer you are using to display the file in reverse?

Comment: Thanks @BoarGules, forgot about the physical aspect of file.

Comment: Actually @0x5453, reversing outside of the logging mechanism could corrupt, but using 'tac' to view the log file is not a bad solution.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer: I should not want to do this.

Because:

> Inserting something at the beginning of a file displaces everything
>   that comes after it, so the bigger the file, the more an insert will
>   cost. That would go counter to the efforts of the logging module to be
>   sparing in its use of resources. – BoarGules Mar 28 at 13:56

Using 'tac' to view the log file is a good solution.